# How can I create a JavaScript global variable?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, global

This is the part of my .html file, where I use an xmlhttp request, and then try to access the JSON object outside of a function.
''''

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>make_activities_table.html</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script>

      var act_obj_array;

      // Get file activities.json and create JSON object
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 ) {
          act_obj_array = JSON.parse( this.responseText);
        }
        console.log(this.responseText);
        console.log('Inside function = ' + act_obj_array);
      };
  
      xmlhttp.open( "GET", "activities.json", true);
      xmlhttp.send();

      console.log( 'Outside function = ' + act_obj_array);

    </script>
  </body>
''''
```

I'm trying to access the JSON object 'act_obj_array' outside of the xmlhttp.onreadystatechange function.  From what I read, in JavaScript, to make a variable global, you define it outside of any function, which, clearly I have done here. But when I console.log 'act_obj_array, outside the function, I get undefined.

activities.json, is a file, that exist in the same directory of my web hosting's server.  It is a JSON formatted file.  I can see the information in the file quite clearly when I console.log( this.responseText );

What do I need to do to create a JSON object from an xmlhttp request, and then be able to access the JSON object from the rest of my code?

Comment: Is it that hard, or that stupid of a question?  I usually have my questions answered by now.  Am I missing something really stupid.  Bad structure?  I want to display my JSON object in a table.  I suppose I could do it inside the function, but, that seems ill structured.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since no one wanted to answer, I came up with a solution, and, I want to work on a second solution.

The solution I have now, I added a function after the line, inside a function:

```
act_obj_array = JSON.parse( this.responseText);
```

which is a function, that builds my table from my JSON object.  At first, I just added the script in the body of the document, but, then, I defined the function in an external JavaScript sheet.  This looked much cleaner.

The other solution, and one I haven't played with yet, is to use the 'fetch' method to read in my JSON file.  That way, I may not have to use a function to create my JSON object.